# Switching from mysql to mysqli issues

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below is some code that works fine, however it used mysql_* and i dont want that anymore. I have tried to redo this section in mysqli but it's not working. I can post my entire code if you wish, but i am certain i know where the issue lies. Below is the code:

Old:

```
public function verifyDatabase()
    {
        include('dbConfig.php');

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE client_email_address = '{$this->_username}' AND client_password = '{$this->_pass_sha1}'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($data))
        {
            list($this->_id) = @array_values(mysql_fetch_assoc($data));
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

New:

```
public function verifyDatabase()
    {
        include('dbConfig.php');

        $data = $db->prepare("SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE client_email_address = ? AND client_password = ? LIMIT 1");
        $data->bind_param($this->_username, $this->_pass_sha1);
        $data->execute();
        $data->store_result();

        if($data->num_rows)
        {
            list($this->_id) = @array_values($data->fetch());
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm still learning mysqli and not quite ready for PDO stuff as i found that a little confusing. As i say, this whole script works perfectly with mysql_* but not so much with mysqli. When i try and log in my form doesnt display any errors nor does it push forward to the next page, so i know its this bit that is the issue

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Well you might also want to avoid suppressing errors with `@`.

Comment: I'm guessing your username is over 16 characters?? The new standard allows usernames of 16 characters or less

Comment: Very hard for me to describe as i am not allow to discuss this project. However when i submit an email and password via my form, this portion should select the client_id that it matches. my username for example might be info@andyholmes.me

Comment: Again, usernames must be less than 16 characters. You may be failing to even connect to the DB because of this.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-names.html

Comment: I'll make it less than 16, but is there anything else in my code that needs to change?

Comment: Yes, follow @Sammitch advice and remove error silencing with @. I wish PHP would remove this feature.

Comment: Have done, seems to be getting somewhere. I'm getting my error message when something doesn't match... however i know it does match! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is advised to use a *helper function*, **either** with old mysql or modern mysqli

```
public function verifyDatabase()
{
    $sql = "SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
    return $this->db->getOne($sql ,$this->_username,$this->_pass_sha1);
}
```

Also note that dbConfig.php **should not** be included in the every method but, but **only once**. While DB handler should be assigned to a class variable in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this. I'm not saying it will fix problems but will be better.

```
public function verifyDatabase()
{
    include('dbConfig.php');

    $data = $db->prepare("SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE client_email_address = ? AND client_password = ? LIMIT 1");
    $data->bind_param($this->_username, $this->_pass_sha1);
    $data->execute();
    $data->store_result();

    if($data->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $result = $data->fetch();
        $this->_id = $result['client_id'];
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also put var_dump($result); after the $result = $data->fetch(); line to print out what exactly is being returned.

Comment: Have you tried putting var_dump($result) AFTER the $resule = $data->fetch(); line? This will show you exactly what the DB fetched for you.